# jest - Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

I'm using vue.js and trying to use jest(with vue utils test) async/await

```js
  it('async/await test', async () => {
    await wrapper.setData({
      foo: 'bar',
    });
    // ...
  });
```

i can use import statement but this error occurs when i run 'yarn test'(jest) command
but i didn't export anything from test file

```
Details:
export default function _asyncToGenerator(fn) {
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1517:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (__test__/TestComponent.test.js:9:49)
```

and this is my config files

// jest.config.json

```
{
  "verbose": true,
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "vue"],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/resources/assets/js/components/$1"
  },
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
    ".*\\.(vue)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest"
  },
  "snapshotSerializers": ["<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-serializer-vue"]
}
```

// babel.config.jss

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/app',
    ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }],
  ],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator',
  ],
};
```

#### environment

```
  System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.19043
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.15.4 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE     
    Yarn: 1.22.10 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\yarn.CMD     
    npm: 6.14.10 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD       
  npmPackages:
    jest: ^27.0.6 => 27.1.0
  +
  "@vue/test-utils": "^1.2.2"
  "@babel/core": "^7.15.0"
  "vue": "^2.6.10"
```

how can i fix this problem??
here is my sample test file code
https://gist.github.com/charmjeh/544455d49ff184750f17df8bb460b876

Comment: I don't think we should export anything from a test file.

Comment: Try `export default _asyncToGenerator` at the end of the function.

Comment: I didn't export anything, so I have no clue where this error from :(
here is my code
https://gist.github.com/charmjeh/544455d49ff184750f17df8bb460b876

Comment: Can you share your TestComponent.test.js file?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/charmjeh/544455d49ff184750f17df8bb460b876
@arieljuod this is my TestComponent.test.js code!

Comment: Why are you doing `export default _asyncToGenerator;` at the end of the file? where's that being defined? I would try removing that line

Comment: Oh sorry it was testing, my original file doesn't have the line. I deleted it from my link!

Comment: The configuration looks right. Do you have a reproducible repo?

Comment: I tried to make reproducible repo with all changes i made for jest and dependent libraries's version are same as original repo, but the issue didn't reproduced hrmm  

this is reproducible repo's link, i'll try to figure out more
https://github.com/charmjeh/reproducible-jest-vue-stackoverflow-68978776  

and another thing to notice is that 
return wrapper.setData({ foo: 'bar'}).then(() => {}) is working

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by installing unit-test and use `yarn test:unit`

```
$ vue add unit-jest
```